# I want to know why when I click Command + click on a text box the drop down menu doesn't give me the option to "Embed in button"

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know why when I click Command + click on a text box  the drop down menu doesn't give me the option to "Embed in button"

[trying to show you that on the course I am taking my instructor has a dropdown menu where he is able to use the "embed in button" and I don't have one when I do the same exact steps as him](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeIF1.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var alertIsVisible: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
    VStack {
            // Target row
    HStack {
                Text("Put the bullseye as close as you can to:")
                Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"100"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            }

            // Slider Row
            HStack {
                Text("1")
                Slider(value: .constant(10))
                Text("100")
            }

            // Button row
    Button(action: {
        print("Button pressed!")
        self.alertIsVisible = true
    }) {
        Text("Hit me please!")
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $alertIsVisible) { () -> Alert in
        return Alert(title: Text("Hello there!"), message: Text("This is my first pop-up."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Awesome!")))
        }

            // Score row
        HStack {
                Text("Start Over")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        ContentView() .previewLayout(PreviewLayout.fixed(width: 896, height: 414))
    }
                }
```